# Beryllium virus detected on bootcamp partition, cannot resolve

Tags: bootcamp, security, big-sur, virus, anti-virus

I recently downloaded Avast and I ran a full deep scan on the MacOS. It detected the Beryllium virus on my bootcamp partition. Resolving the problem through Avast is not successful. I then booted up Windows 10 and run a full scan (full and offline modes) using both Avast and Microsoft Defender, however Beryllium was not detected. I then went back to MacOS and did a full scan with Avast and still detected Beryllium. What should I do moving forward?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The `pagefile.sys` file is used by Windows as [virtual memory](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hiberfil-pagefile-swapfile-sys-windows). Basically, Avast running under macOS is giving you a false positive and thus can be ignored. I tested this by performing a clean install of Windows 10 (20H2) in a VMware Fusion Player (12.1.1) virtual machine. Next, I installed Avast and found no malware. However, I wanted Avast to scan `pagefile.sys` for viruses. Below is the procedure I used.

1. I restarting Windows to boot to the Windows Recovery Environment. Basically, I held down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while restarting Windows.
2. I navigated to a Windows Command Prompt window.
3. I entered the following commands. Basically, I wanted a copy of `pagefile.sys`.

   ```
   c:
   attrib -h -s pagefile.sys
   copy pagefile.sys pagefile.bin
   attrib +h +s pagefile.sys
   exit
   ```
4. I booted back to Windows.
5. Using the File Explorer, I selected to run a scan on `pagefile.bin`, as shown below. For a better view, click on the image or open the image in a new window.

   [image]

   The result is shown below.

   [image]

So Avast under Windows is ignoring the `pagefile.sys` file, but does not under macOS. Being this test was made from a clean install of Windows, I assume this found malware threat is a false positive and can therefore be ignored.

Comment: Addendum: If you want avast to shut up, it should be safe to delete `pagefile.sys` from the macOS side; then the next time you boot Windows, it will automatically re-create it with clean contents.

Comment: @zwol: After doing some further testing, I found there may be no malware threat detected or a different malware threat detected such as `Chan` or `Sf:ShellCode-R[Trj]`. Both Microsoft Defender Antivirus and Avast have patterns used to detect malware. I *think* some of these patterns are being written to virtual memory (`pagefile.sys`) when Microsoft Defender Antivirus or Avast executes.  So, while what you suggest will probably work, the fix may be temporary. If I am right, then any execution of Microsoft Defender Antivirus or Avast may recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky Threats says that the Beryllium virus is harmless, so you mightn't need to worry about it. I have zero knowledge of computer code, so if you still want it gone, I have no idea how.